# How to display Attribute Group Name on Product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I want to show the Attribute Group names, not only the attributes in additional tab of product page.

I try [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438750/how-to-display-attribute-group-name-on-product-page) but nothing change in product page.

Why it doesn't work? Is it possible this solution have problem?

### **EDIT:**

I try below code but it show all the attributes group name but I want for attributes that they are in one group, show the group name of these attributes once. For example one product just have one attribute and should show one group name but when I use below code it show all group's name that they don't show.

How can I correct this code?

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>

    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php    
    $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
    <?php 
        $attributeGroupCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_group_collection');
        foreach ($attributeGroupCollection as $attributeGroup) {
            echo "\n\nGroup Name: " . $attributeGroup->getAttributeGroupName();
            $attributeCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
            ->setAttributeGroupFilter($attributeGroup->getAttributeGroupId());
        }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: That was referenced from here: http://www.webguys.de/magento/attributes-als-attribute-set-im-webshop-darstellen check each lines. Hope you have already cleared your cache.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri: Yes, I checked that page, and also I cleared cache several times!

Comment: Which `catalog.xml` file did you edit? Can you show path to your xml? It should be of your active theme.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri: I edited `catalog.xml` in `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\catalog.xml` . In this path : `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout` I don't have `catalog.xml` .

Comment: What's your theme? Can you give me your site url?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri: Theme name is celebrity, and I worked on it in local.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26327/discussion-between-adarsh-khatri-and-elham-gdz).